# Creating Seo clean urls in yii1.1.x

Tags: php, yii, seo

i am creating seo clean url for my site .
i want to display userdetails, if user hit the url like http://localhost/2015/mysite/user/username for that i have created         urlManager in yii
ex:

```
'urlManager'=>array(

    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,

    'rules'=>array( 

         array(
             'class'=>'ext.sitemapgenerator.SGUrlRule',
             // Optional. Default: '/sitemap'
         ),             
        '<view:(about|guidelines|faq|termsofuse|privacypolicy|help-us|spread-word)>' => 'site/page',
        'contact'=>'site/contact',                                  
        '/'=>'site/index',

        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<active>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',                  
              '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>', 
        '<action:(login)>' => 'site/login',
        '<action:(signup)>' => 'user/signup',
        'user/<username:\w+>/*' => 'user/userdetailsseo',  //user is my controller 

    ),
)
```

So Now if the user search username i am redirecting to user/userdetailsseom

```
'/<username:\w+>/*' => 'user/userdetailsseo'  working perfect for http://localhost/2015/mysite/username,
'user/<username:\w+>/*' =>'user/userdetailsseo'  it's not working for http://localhost/2015/mysite/user/username i am getting page not found error...
```

Anyone can help me please...
Thanks..